# Deploy React app in Azure, getting "didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8080"

Tags: reactjs, azure, visual-studio-code, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I'm using this tutorial
https://medium.com/geekculture/easiest-way-to-host-your-react-app-azure-vs-code-8046f9f7fb0b
to deploy my newly created React App to Azure App service. However I kept getting the error below. Any idea why?

I tried all kinds of troubleshooting from the internet such as

Set `WEBSITES_PORT` and `PORT` Setting to `80`

but no luck so far.

```
2021-10-05T16:31:37.859Z INFO  - Initiating warmup request to container managementlnxdev_0_9e7876cc for site managementlnxdev
2021-10-05T16:31:53.746Z INFO  - Waiting for response to warmup request for container managementlnxdev_0_9e7876cc. Elapsed time = 15.8869901 sec
2021-10-05T16:32:08.969Z ERROR - Container managementlnxdev_0_9e7876cc for site managementsitedev has exited, failing site start
2021-10-05T16:32:08.972Z ERROR - Container managementlnxdev_0_9e7876cc didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8080, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.
2021-10-05T16:32:08.989Z INFO  - Stopping site managementlnxdev because it failed during startup.
```

Comment: Could you please open the app in portal and go to diagnose and solve problems > Availability & performance > Application logs to isolate the issue.  Which sku you are using?
Also, check this link  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/faq-app-service-linux 
Let us know.

Comment: @[warheat1990](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3226114/warheat1990) Any update to the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this issue when working on Deploying a ReactJS Application to Azure Web App for Containers

When I deploy the app to the Azure, I will get the error below:

```
2021-06-10T10:29:05.571Z INFO  - Initiating warmup request to container mediumblogreact_5app for site devopsapptest
2021-06-10T10:29:07.733Z ERROR - Container mediumblogreact_5app for site devopsapptest has exited, failing site start
2021-06-10T10:29:07.737Z ERROR - Container mediumblogreact_5app didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 80, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.
```

Change the port to 3000 instead of 80, which is what App Service assumes your custom container is listening on by default.

Below CLI/PowerShell commands will help in changing the port values:

In Azure CLI:

```
az webapp config appsettings set --resource-group <rg-group-name> --name <web-app-name> --settings WEBSITES_PORT=8000
```

In Azure PowerShell:

```
Set-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName <rg-group-name> -Name <web-app-name> -AppSettings @{"WEBSITES_PORT"="8000"}
```

**Note**: Your container can only expose one port for HTTP requests right now with App Service.

You might also want to include the EXPOSE your-port command in your project's Docker file.

**Resources**: [Configure a custom container for Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-custom-container?pivots=container-linux#configure-port-number)